JupyterLab textarea widget doesn't accept 'enter' or 'tab' key presses?
So the problem is that when I create a textarea widget and try to type something in the textarea, the textarea doesn't observe 'enter' or 'tab' key presses. I'm still able to copy-paste text with tabs and newlines in there, but I can't type them in directly.
Currently as a workaround I've set the textarea handler to check if the textarea.value ends in '\\n', and then edit that to effective newline, which works, but I don't want to keep typing '\\n' everytime I would normally press enter.
Is this textarea behaviour normal, and how to properly fix this so that 'tab' and 'enter' actually work.
